# Is there a sufficiently large vertex set in a 3-uniform hypergraph, which satisfies the following condition?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hypergraphs

Suppose $\mathcal{H}=(V,\mathcal{E})$ is a $3$-uniform hypergraph on $n$ vertices, such that for any non-empty vertex set $S\subseteq V$ with $|S|\le t$ (where $(t<n)$), there is a $v\in S$ and an edge $E\in\mathcal{E}$ such that $E\cap S=\{v\}$.

Now **my question** is: is there an $0<\alpha<1-\frac{t}{n}$, such that we can find a subset $U\subset V$ satisfying "$|U|\ge(1-\alpha)n$, and for any $U_1\subseteq U$, there exists a $v\in U_1$ an edge $E\in\mathcal{E}$ such that $E\cap U_1=\{v\}$ " ? If there is, how large can $U$ be? (I want it to be as large as possible.)

Comment: @bof Yes, $S$ is a non-empty subset of $V$. I missed one condition on $U$ before, and I have added it in the question.

Comment: If $S\subseteq V$ and $|S|=t=n-1=|V|-1$, how can there possibly be an edge $E$ with $|E|=3$ and $|E\cap V|=1$? Could you please give an example of a hypergraph $\mathcal H$ satisfying your condition?